# Select2 and Datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables, autocomplete, editor, jquery-select2

I'm having trouble getting Select2.js to work together with the Datatables Editor inputs.
Can anyone who has done it show me how?

The context is the following: after opening the form in the Editor, I want to use Select2 in text capos (pseudo-selects) to serve as auto complete. The part of showing options is functional, the part of saving the DB from the Editor too... the problem is when I open the line to edit again (after refreshing the page) the information is no longer filled in in the inputs. Any suggestion?

Html code:

```
<table class="table nowrap" id="tbbl" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Marca</th>
<th>Cor</th>
<th>Estado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: 'includes/table.sells.php',
        table: '#tbbl',
        fields: [


            {
                label: 'Marca:',
                name: 'marca',
                type: 'select2',
                opts: {
                    "theme": "bootstrap",
                    tags: true,
                    minimumInputLength: 0,
                    placeholder: 'Marca',
                    allowClear: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'select2.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        data: function (params) {
                            return {
                                q: params.term,
                                nomecampo: "marca",
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (data) {
                            return {
                                results: data
                            };
                        },
                        cache: false,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Cor:',
                name: 'cor',
                type: 'select2',
                opts: {
                    "theme": "bootstrap",
                    tags: true,
                    minimumInputLength: 0,
                    placeholder: 'Cor',
                    allowClear: true,
                    multiple: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'select2.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        data: function (params) {
                            return {
                                q: params.term,
                                nomecampo: "cor",
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (data) {
                            return {
                                results: data
                            };
                        },
                        cache: false,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "label": "Estado:",
                "name": "estado",
                "type": "select",
                "options": ["Pendente", "Concluído", "Rejeitado", "Outro"]
            },
        ]
    });
    var table = $('#tbbl').DataTable({
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
        scrollX: false,
        scrollY: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        "select": true,
        lengthChange: false,
        stateSave: false,
        "stateDuration": 10,
        deferRender: true,
        responsive: true,
        "paging": false,
        "order": [
            [0, "desc"]
        ],
        ajax: 'includes/table.sells.php',
        columns: [

            {
                "data": "estado"
            },

            {
                "data": "marca"
            },

            {
                "data": "cor"
            },

        ],
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
            this.api().buttons().container().appendTo('#tbbl_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)');
        },
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [{
                extend: "create",
                editor: editor,
                className: 'btn-group btn btn-primary',
                text: 'add',
                key: 'a'
            },
            {
                extend: "edit",
                editor: editor,
                className: 'btn-group btn btn-warning',
                text: 'edit',
                key: 'e'
            },
            {
                extend: "remove",
                editor: editor,
                className: 'btn-group btn btn-danger',
                text: 'del',
                key: 'x'
            },


        ],
    });
});

</script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['q'])){ $_GET['q']="";}
if (!isset($_GET['nomecampo'])){ $_GET['nomecampo']="";}
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=61HSD65G', 'D65G', 'ASDD561HSD65G');
$db->exec("set names utf8");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ".$_GET['nomecampo']." FROM `sells` WHERE ".$_GET['nomecampo']." LIKE :pesquisa");
$stmt->execute(array(':pesquisa' => '%' . $_GET['q'] . '%'));
$results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $results[] = array('id' => $row[$_GET['nomecampo']], 'text' => $row[$_GET['nomecampo']]);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Many thanks in advance!

I want use select2.js as autocomplete, whit input whit simple text option, and ohter whit multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. The problem was in something so basic: it had to return the value when editing, from the string sent "initialValue: true". That part apparently already tried, the problem is that it was sending the original value with double quotes.
Thanks to those who tried.